# Does MASM change instructions behind your back?

Tags: assembly, x86, x86-64, masm

I was surprised by the following when reading the [HLA faq](http://webster.cs.ucr.edu/AsmTools/HLA/HLADoc/HTMLDoc/hlafaq.txt):

> MASM has a nasty habit of changing instructions behind your
>           back.  HLA also seems to have this same problem.

I then searched the web but found nothing regarding this. Is it true or just a myth?

Comment: Not aware of any specific cases where it does, but it certainly *could*.  I know the old A86 assembler used to emit different sequences of compatible code as part of the piracy detection mechanism.

Comment: Early MASM was a bit, erm, special.  If you can dig up details on the Borland's QUIRKS mode used in tasm then you'll find a good list.  Kinda hard though, this is pre-internet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's kind of half-true. Some instructions can be encoded in more than one way, and at times (for reasons they've never explained) Microsoft has changed how they encode a few particular instructions.

Since version 6, it's also had a multi-pass mode that can/will encode jumps using the smallest form of a jump that will "reach" the destination. Up through 5.x, you had to manually specify near vs. far jumps, and if you guessed wrong, on the second pass it would produce a "phase error". Starting with v6, it'll automatically adjust the size. Since that changes the size of the instruction, that can force other surrounding jumps to change as well (and, likewise, in the other direction, a smaller encoding for a jump may reduce code size that another jump could reach it's destination with a smaller encoding).

This is *not*, however, a "nasty habit" from most people's perspective -- quite the contrary, most people rather like it to automatically encode the instructions as efficiently as possible. There are a few cases (e.g., self-modifying code) where you need to prevent it, but *those* are the ones that usually qualify as "nasty habits" (at least if you really do them habitually).

Comment: So many good answers, but since I have to choose one, I choose this, sorry for the other guys.

Answer (score 2):

MASM can change things on you. For example, it can fix your conditional jumps. That is if you write:

```
    add ax,bx
    jnz NotZero

    ...
NotZero:
```

If `NotZero` is outside the range of a conditional jump, MASM can rewrite your code as:

```
    add ax,bx
    jz Zero
    jmp NotZero
Zero:
    ...
NotZero:
```

As I recall, there are command line switches to prevent that. You can also specifically say, `jnz near NotZero` to prevent it. If you do that and the target is outside the range of the conditional, you'll get an error.

I recall that MASM did some other, similar, things, but it's been a very long time. I don't recall what those specific things were.

Answer (score 1):

This probably is not what you're looking for, but I've experienced cases where MASM doesn't produce the same output for the same input as other similar assemblers (NASM, for example).  That is, a slightly different byte-sequence that disassembles to the same thing.

Typically, it's not an issue at all though, and the only reason I even noticed it was because of a weird case that I needed certain bits in the instruction to be a particular value; with one assembler it was fine, and with the other, it wasn't and I had to apply manual fix-ups.

Hope that helps.

Comment: "That is, a slightly different byte-sequence that disassembles to the same thing. "

Wow, I didn't know that such a thing was even possible? I thought that there is a one-to-one mapping between assembly and machine language.

Comment: Nah, it's rare.  One easy example that isn't quite the same is as what i described but should suffice: try assembling `int3` and `int 3` in nasm.  You should get something like `\xcc` and `\xcc03`, respectively. Fun fact: some debuggers have problems parsing the latter (since they expect a single-byte instruction).  Have fun!

Comment: I believe some of the MOV and maybe even ADD instructions have more than one binary encoding that will do the same thing.  Just going from memory though, it's been a LOOONG time since I've dealt with that.  :-)

Answer (score 0):

I think this "changing" is about instruction scheduling and peep-hole optimizations. You can escape this when you write your code with "cat >pgm.o".